# Redux: (Domain data and) App state vs. UI state

Tags: redux

From the Redux docs on [Basic State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure#basic-state-shape):

> Most applications deal with multiple types of data, which can be broadly divided into three categories:
>
> 1. **Domain data**: data that the application needs to show, use, or modify (such as "all of the Todos retrieved from the server")
> 2. **App state**: data that is specific to the application's behavior (such as "Todo #5 is currently selected", or "there is a request in progress to fetch Todos")
> 3. **UI state**: data that represents how the UI is currently displayed (such as "The EditTodo modal dialog is currently open")

The **Domain data** part is clear to me, but I can still vaguely distinguish between the **App state** and **UI state**. The examples given for the App state part: "*Todo #5 is currently selected*", or "*there is a request in progress to fetch Todos*", sound pretty much **UI state**-ish. How are they classified as **App state**, but not **UI state**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote that Redux docs page.  (4 years ago!  wow.  time flies!)

I was trying to give some broad examples as a way to illustrate the concepts, not make strict categorizations.  You could probably make a legit argument that "which todo is selected" is more "UI"-ish than "App"-ish.  On the other hand, I'd say that "current selected todo" is more likely to relate to something else that the app can do, like "delete this todo", "mark this todo as completed", etc, while "the modal is open" is strictly about how the UI is being displayed.

Comment: Wew, thanks again then @markerikson for your extended explanation!! :))

I know that it's not a strict categorization, but would it be fair to say that the app state is a state that more than one UI component depend on / make use of?